# Text appearing with no line space when browser is shrunk

Tags: html, css, text

I've got a problem with my text when the browser is shrunk or on a mobile device. [Here is a screenshot to help explain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VECiy.jpg) On a larger screen the 'matched' text is on the same line as 'what is' so there is no problem. Below is the code I'm using at the minute. I would like the gap to be the same as the one below 'matched'. Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">

<img class="aligncenter wp-image-1015" 
src="https://www.thesurebettor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/what-is-
matched-betting-1.jpg" alt="" width="750" height="431" />
<div class="text-wrapper"><p>What is matched</p><p>betting?</P>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.aligncenter {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

 .outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

 .text-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 35px;
  transform: translateX(-90%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 52px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two paragraphs for the text, but semantically it is one paragraph:

```
<p>What is matched betting?</p>
```

This is also the root of your problem - you can solve it using two paragraphs by ensuring the line height and the margins/padding match - but using a single paragraph would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `line-height: 1` on `.text-wrapper` div.

```css
.aligncenter {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.text-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 35px;
  transform: translateX(-90%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 52px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
    <img class="aligncenter wp-image-1015" 
src="https://www.thesurebettor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/what-is-
matched-betting-1.jpg" alt="" width="750" height="431" />
    <div class="text-wrapper"><p>What is matched</p><p>betting?</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You written wrong html. please make it correct.

```css
.aligncenter {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

 .outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

 .text-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 35px;
  transform: translateX(-90%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 52px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">

<img class="aligncenter wp-image-1015" 
src="https://www.thesurebettor.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/what-is-
matched-betting-1.jpg" alt="" width="750" height="431" />
<div class="text-wrapper"><p>What is matched</p><p>betting?</p></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click here for the Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQgkz.jpg)

> Your issue is not reproducible from my end, check the above snapshot.
>   It may be caused because of some other styling in your css. Anyhow
>   please make **text responsive**.

Please include *font-size: 100%* for the *body* and use media query to target the screen where the text is overlapping

eg., 
*@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 535px){*

*//give font-size in percentage for text-wrapper p and if required include line-height as well*

*}*